# Python Sqlite3 Get Sqlite Connection path

Tags: python, sqlite

Given an sqlite3 connection object, how can retrieve the file path to the sqlite3 file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [Python connection object](http://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c) doesn't store this information.

You could store the path before you open the connection:

```
path = '/path/to/database/file.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
```

or you can ask the database itself what connections it has, using the [`database_list` pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list):

```
for id_, name, filename in conn.execute('PRAGMA database_list'):
    if name == 'main' and filename is not None:
        path = filename
        break
```

If you used a [connection URI](https://www.sqlite.org/uri.html) (connecting with the `sqlite3.connect()` parameter `uri=True`), the filename will not include the URI parameters or the `file://` prefix.

Answer (score 24):

We can use the PRAGMA database_list command.

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("PRAGMA database_list")
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

The third parameter (row[2]) is the file name of the database.
Note that there could be more databases attached to SQLite engine.

```
$ ./list_dbs.py 
0 main /home/user/dbs/test.db
2 movies /home/user/dbs/movies.db
```

The above is a sample output of a script that contains the Python code.

Comment: This answer works, and should have been the accepted one.

Answer (score 6):

Referencing Martijn Pieters, except hardcoding is a must, you should do this:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db = os.path.join(path, 'file.db')

conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
```